# Как в Webpack 4 настроить Css Modules?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

как в Webpack настроить CSS Modules чтобы генерировать вот такие классы (Hesh)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: отличный вопрос

Comment: https://develoger.com/how-to-obfuscate-css-class-names-with-react-and-webpack-20e2b5c49cda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это можно делать только в `react.js` приложениях  в простом `HTML` файле такое у вас не получитсья

**1 способ**. В *create-react-app* это делаетсья с помощью конфигурации **webpack**.

Чтобы получить конфигурацию webpack-а после create-react-app нам надо сделать `npm-run-eject`
после в консоли получим такой вопрос

**Are you sure want to eject?**

после нажатия **Y** как только консоль завершил свою работу вы увидите в папке проекта два новых папок `scripts` и `config`

Первую папку не трогаем.Во второй папке(`config`) находим файл **webpack.config.dev.js**
В этой конфигурации находим строку где написано `loader:require.resolve('css-loader')`и пишем следующее

```
{
   test:/\.css$/,
   use: [
      require.resolve('style-loader'),
      {
         loader:require.resolve('css-loader')
         options: {
            importLoaders:1,
           //Вот с этой строки начинаем менять webpack.config
            modules:true, // 1
            localIdentName: '[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]' //2
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Эти же изменение скопируете и вставляете в файл **webpack.config.prod.js** для того чтобы и в продакшене у вас было тоже самое.
Только не надо эти изменения перезаписать вместо 
`minimize:true` или `sourceMap:shouldUseSourceMap`

Проста напишите эти две изменения после них.

Теперь работаем с компонентом. 
У вас должно быть 2 файла в одной папке `App.js` и `App.css`

Также для теста напишите эти классы в свой App.css

```
.blue {
    background:blue;
    font-weight:bold;
}
.red {
   color:red;
   border:2px solid green;
}
```

Импортируем css из нашего компонента таким способом.

```
import classesFromApp from "./App.css";
```

И последний штрих используем их в JSX таким образом

```
<div className={classesFromApp.red}>

</div>
```

или же

```
<div className={classesFromApp.blue}>

</div>
```

И после компиляции в консоли вы получаете такой `CSS` класс **app__blue___2XkY0** :)

**2 способ** установка  в проекте Laravel  **CSS-Modules** в **Laravel-mix**

> Надо загрузить и установить пакет **laravel-mix-react-css-modules**

И потом установить в **webpack.mix.js** таким образом

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');
require('laravel-mix-react-css-modules');

mix.react('resources/assets/app.js', 'public/js')
   .reactCSSModules('[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]');
```

И запустить также с компонентом **App.js** в одной папке с **App.css** как указано наверху и все.

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ

Comment: @bringonor всегда пожалуйста